react native expo with gradlew
Run gradlew
13s
Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Welcome to Gradle 8.6!
Here are the highlights of this release:

Configurable encryption key for configuration cache
Build init improvements
Build authoring improvements
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
:ReactNative:Running '[node, /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js, config]' command failed.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 401
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.


Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 12s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

I have already used npx expo-doctor
npx expo-doctor --fix-dependencies
npx expo install --check
I need to build my react native application with expo

Can you share your "Project\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties" file?
